# What's the best way to create a new view with filtered values based on latest date in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a view like this:

[image]

I need a new view like this:

[image]

I know that I should create a temp table, order by date where ProductID = 'abc' and select the first row of temp table, create a newtable, order by date where ProductID = 'def' and select the first row of new table and use something like

```
INSERT INTO mergedtable
   SELECT * FROM newtable
   UNION
   SELECT * FROM temptable
```

in a loop for all the Product ID. But is there any better way?

Comment: Please don't use images for data - use formatted text.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date = (select max(t2.date) from t t2 where t2.productid = t.productid);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select ID
, ProductID
, [Date]

from (
    select ID
    , ProductID
    , [Date]
    , max([Date]) over (partition by ProductID) as MaxDate

    from #product
) q

where [Date] = MaxDate
```